# What events trigger workflows with the `on.pull_request.tags` trigger?

Tags: github, github-actions

The [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags) state the following:

> For a `pull_request` event, only branches and tags on the base are evaluated.

As far as I am aware, the base parameter of a pull request cannot be a tag, but rather must be a branch. With this in mind, would a workflow that contains exclusively the following trigger:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    tags:
      - '*'
```

ever actually run?

Comment: As you can [update a tag (to another commit)](https://www.toolsqa.com/git/git-delete-tag/), I guess it's referring to this kind of event. (There is another good reference about tags [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)). I never tested it with GHA but I'm curious now :D